# How to combine - overwrite key value pairs in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which has some entries. I've replaced real data with "dummydata" . But "dummydata" is the same value of array[0] and array[1] . As you can see blelow there are some differences in some keys :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [contact_id] => dummydata
            [customer_code] => dummydata
            [customer_name] => dummydata
            [territory] => dummydata       
            [firstname] => dummydata
            [lastname] => dummydata
            [contact_type_description] => dummydata
            [contact_is_primary] => 1
            [mailing_street] => dummydata
            [mailing_postal_code] => dummydata
            [mailing_city] => dummydata
            [mailing_country] => dummydata
            [email] => dummydata
            [mobile_phone] => dummydata
            [phone] => dummydata
            [is_processed] => 0
            [exact_email_found] => 0
            [half_email_found] => 0
            [possible_by_postal_code] => 1 // * Keep this line but look below
            [found_first_name] => 0
            [found_last_name] => 0 // * Keep this line but look below
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [contact_id] => dummydata
            [customer_code] => dummydata
            [customer_name] => dummydata
            [territory] => dummydata
            [firstname] => dummydata
            [lastname] => dummydata
            [contact_type_description] => dummydata
            [contact_is_primary] => 1
            [mailing_street] => dummydata
            [mailing_postal_code] => dummydata
            [mailing_city] => dummydata
            [mailing_country] => dummydata
            [email] => dummydata
            [mobile_phone] => 
            [phone] => dummydata
            [is_processed] => 0
            [exact_email_found] => 0
            [half_email_found] => 0
            [possible_by_postal_code] => 0 // * HERE is the difference
            [found_first_name] => 0
            [found_last_name] => 1 //  * HERE is the difference with the above
        )

    [2] => Array // No need to look it's just to show that array continues
        (
            [contact_id] => dummydata-different
            [customer_code] => dummydata-different
            [customer_name] => dummydata-different
            [territory] => dummydata-different  
            [firstname] => dummydata-different
            [lastname] => dummydata-different
            [contact_type_description] => dummydata-different
            [contact_is_primary] => 0
            [mailing_street] => dummydata-different
            [mailing_postal_code] => dummydata-different
            [mailing_city] => dummydata-different
            [mailing_country] => dummydata-different
            [email] => 
            [mobile_phone] => 
            [phone] => 
            [is_processed] => 0
            [exact_email_found] => 0
            [half_email_found] => 0
            [possible_by_postal_code] => 0
            [found_first_name] => 1
            [found_last_name] => 0
        )
```

**How can i make the above array merge all the same data but overwrite the ones that are different. For example the result i am trying to accomplish :**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [contact_id] => dummydata
            [customer_code] => dummydata
            [customer_name] => dummydata
            [territory] => dummydata       
            [firstname] => dummydata
            [lastname] => dummydata
            [contact_type_description] => dummydata
            [contact_is_primary] => 1
            [mailing_street] => dummydata
            [mailing_postal_code] => dummydata
            [mailing_city] => dummydata
            [mailing_country] => dummydata
            [email] => dummydata
            [mobile_phone] => dummydata
            [phone] => dummydata
            [is_processed] => 0
            [exact_email_found] => 0
            [half_email_found] => 0
            [possible_by_postal_code] => 1 // * This becomes one from the merging
            [found_first_name] => 0
            [found_last_name] => 1 // * This becomes one from the merging
        )


    [1] => Array
        (
            [contact_id] => dummydata-different
            [customer_code] => dummydata-different
            [customer_name] => dummydata-different
            [territory] => dummydata-different  
            [firstname] => dummydata-different
            [lastname] => dummydata-different
            [contact_type_description] => dummydata-different
            [contact_is_primary] => 0
            [mailing_street] => dummydata-different
            [mailing_postal_code] => dummydata-different
            [mailing_city] => dummydata-different
            [mailing_country] => dummydata-different
            [email] => 
            [mobile_phone] => 
            [phone] => 
            [is_processed] => 0
            [exact_email_found] => 0
            [half_email_found] => 0
            [possible_by_postal_code] => 0
            [found_first_name] => 1
            [found_last_name] => 0
        )
```

Tried different things with the functions that are provided by PHP but this got me confused.

Comment: Exactly what you want to do ? keep record with value 1 and overwrite if value is 0 in one array and 1 in another table ? or replace whole bunch of array ?

Comment: I think you will have to check/merge them manually as all functions won't be able to "know or guess" which value from which array "wins".

Comment: @jilesh I want to "merge" array[0] and array[1] so it becomes array[0] but that array[0] to have "1" be overwritten. More specifically, Array[0] has `"found_last_name" => "0"` but Array[1] has `"found_last_name" => "1"` . I want the new array which will be created to have `"found_last_name" => "1"` and the other duplicate to be removed.

Comment: @AlexOdenthal So it is completely a custom function right? Is there a php function which could be helpful?

Comment: I think you should try with array_diff() or array_diff_assoc() and compare both array and get difference values and merge it in first array using array_merge() or in a way to get appropriate result for more info about array_diff : http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I say keep it simple *(and fast)*:

```
foreach ($arr[0] as $k=>$v) {
    if ($v > $arr[1][$k]) $arr[1][$k] = $v;
}

array_shift($arr);
```

Notice: if the two items you want to compare aren't at the beginning of the array, use `unset` and `array_values` instead of `array_shift`.

Comment: That works! But what happens if an entry is not in the next position? Could you edit this so it could work even if it's randomized?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos: I added a notice for these cases, but obviously you need to know in advance which items you want to compare.

Comment: I guess it will work if i sort them by their `contact_id` right?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos: what you asked in your question is no more clear now, I suggest to post an other question, with an array (that can be copy/pasted directly in a php code, an array definition in other words) that better describes your situation with more items but with less keys (3 or 4 should suffice)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this :

```
$result = array_map("unserialize", array_unique(array_map("serialize", $input_array)));
```

`$input_array` is the array with duplicate values.

So here what basically happens is that first array gets converted to single dimensional array then duplicates value are removed and then again it gets converted to multi dimensional one.

Comment: Didn't quite work. Does array_unique has a specifier?

Comment: @AntonisTsimourtos My bad I didn't see that one of the value of key were different in the first two array. This only works if all keys are the same. But what you are trying to achieve is quite not possible with what you have specified till now. For example in your desired result `is_processed` is 0 for both arrays so according to logic they both should be merged too as earlier array with `dummydata` were merged. I guess you want them to be merged only if specific fields are same because `is_process` is same for all.